# How to format this date (dd/mm/yyyy) into (j M Y) in PHP?

Tags: php, date

I'm trying to convert this date format (in PHP): "dd/mm/yyyy", for example 18/08/2011, into "j M Y" which should output something like this, "18 August 2011".

If anyone could help, it would be much appreciated,
Thanks.

Comment: Danny you must accept any question if you find Answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP convert one date into another date format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/php-convert-one-date-into-another-date-format)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php 
   $str = "18/08/2011";
    preg_match("|(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)|", $str, $match);
    $str = $match[2]."/".$match[1]."/".$match[2];
    echo $your_format = date("j M Y", strtotime($str)); //strtotime() expects mm/dd/yyyy
    //returns 18 Aug 2008
?>
```

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/29439.php

Comment: I need to convert 18/08/2011 into 18 August 2011. When I change the $str variable to 18/08/2011 it outputs 1 Jan 1970 ??

Comment: it should work right now

Answer (score 3):

If you are using PHP >= 5.3 you may try the DateTime class.

```
<?php
  $dateString = '18/08/2011';
  $dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $dateString);

  echo date('d M Y', $dt->getTimestamp());
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
$oldDate = "18/08/2011";
$dateArr = explode("/", $oldDate);
$newDate = date("j M Y", mktime(0,0,0,$dateArr[1],$dateArr[0],$dateArr[2]));
```

Should work as is. Notice the order of the `$dateArr` elements listed in `mktime`.

Answer (score 0):

strtotime() is fine, but it runs the risk of returning unexpected results due to the date configuration of your system.  Just to be extra safe, I favour using a look-up array.

```
<?php

function dateReformat( $date )
{
    $monthList = array
    (
        'January',
        'February',
        'March',
        'April',
        'May',
        'June',
        'July',
        'August',
        'September',
        'October',
        'November',
        'December'
    );

    $tmp = explode( '/', $date );
    $month = $monthList[ $tmp[1]-1 ];

    return "{$tmp[0]} {$month} {$tmp[2]}";
}

echo dateReformat( '12/05/1980' );
```