# How do I convert this time format?

Tags: php, mysql, time

```
2011-07-13 02:38:31
```

^ MySQL format.

I would like to use PHP to convert it to another format like , July 13, 2011 2:38 am.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to format this date (dd/mm/yyyy) into (j M Y) in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692294/how-to-format-this-date-dd-mm-yyyy-into-j-m-y-in-php)

Comment: check this:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487921/php-convert-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-dd-mm-yyyy-not-in-sql][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487921/php-convert-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-dd-mm-yyyy-not-in-sql

Comment: check this:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487921/php-convert-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-dd-mm-yyyy-not-in-sql][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487921/php-convert-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-dd-mm-yyyy-not-in-sql

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php
$time_from_db = '2011-07-13 02:38:31';

echo date('F j, Y g:i a', strtotime($time_from_db));
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
echo date("F j, Y g:i a", strtotime("2011-07-13 02:38:31"));
```

[demo](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/487bc.php)

Comment: edited! [demo](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/d6834.php) (you could remove your downvote,maybe?)

Comment: Yes, which is exactly like mine posted 8mins ago. I removed the down vote obviously.

Answer (score 1):

```
$yourdatevar = date("F j, Y, g:i a", strtotime($yourdatevar)); // March 10, 2001, 5:16 pm
```

Taken right from: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php